# pattern search and display the last occuring pattern?

Tags: grep, sed, regular-expression, awk

I have a log file containing **startup** and **shutdown** times for everday.

I want to see the last pattern for startup and shutdown (which is located at the end of the file being updated everyday).

Also I dont want all the lines between the startup and shutdown.I want only a few (let's say 3) lines after the last startup and a few (let's say 3 lines) after the last shutdown.

Any suggestions for a one liner?

Comment: I tried like `less logfile | sed -ne'/startup/,+3p' -e '/shutdown/,+3p'` but it did'nt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `sed` and `grep` if you don't mind to reverse the (extracted) lines of the log file twice (see [How can I reverse the lines in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742466/how-can-i-reverse-the-lines-in-a-file)).

```
# test case
echo '
startup 1
shutdown 1
startup 2
shutdown 2
startup 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
shutdown 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
' | 
tail -r | sed -n -e '1,/startup/p' | tail -r | grep -E -A 3 '(startup|shutdown)'


# output
startup 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
--
shutdown 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use grep instead sed wit option '--after-context'.

**Example:**

```
cat logfile | grep --after-context=3 startup
```

Comment: Useless use of cat